# ERROR with a basic user interaction program in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Can some please advise me of what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm new to visual basic 2012

What I am trying to do:

One input is saved into an Integer variable. The other input is saved into a Byte variable.
The output is calculated as the Integer * Byte/100 to the power 2.
If the user enters a non-numeric value, and clicks the button, show an error of "Illegal Value entered" using Messagebox. 
If the user enters an "out of range"  number, show an error of "input not in valid range" using Messagebox.

This is the code that I have:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim T1 As String
    Dim T2 As String
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Byte
    Dim c As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            TextBox1.Text = False
            TextBox2.Text = False
            a = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            b = CByte(TextBox2.Text)
            c = a * b / 100
            c = c * a * b / 100 ^ 2
            Label3.Text = "Output:" + c.ToString()


        Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            MessageBox.Show("Illegal Value Entered")

        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            MessageBox.Show("Input not in valid range")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Some exception has occured")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I think I meant to to be able to enter an integer and byte the answer comes out in the Output textbox

Comment: i would like to enter an integer or byte variable and then have the answer go into the output box. if its not in range then it would get one of the Catch exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the expressions TextBox1.Text = False (and for TextBox2) this would always force CInt() and CByte() to parse a string 'False' (not a user provided number). Your code should look like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        a = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        b = CByte(TextBox2.Text)
        c = a * b / 100
        c = c * a * b / 100 ^ 2
        Label3.Text = "Output:" + c.ToString()


    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show("Illegal Value Entered")

    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show("Input not in valid range")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Some exception has occured")

    End Try
End Sub
```

If you want to clear the numbers from textboxes after calculation, then please put these lines of code right after Label3.Text = ... line

```
TextBox1.Text = False
TextBox2.Text = False
```

[CByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ssb79wt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) documentation clearly states that

> If expression lies outside the acceptable range for the byte subtype,
>   an error occurs.

CByte(...) constructor would not be able to parse any number greater than 255.